# Simplifying a fraction.

Tags: fractions

The answer of a "solve for x" equation equaled to -10/-19, and the website on which I am practicing says it needs to be simplified, but I have no idea how. Help?

Comment: Cancel $-1$...${}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{-10}{-19}=\dfrac{-1}{-1}\dfrac{10}{19}=\boxed{\dfrac{10}{19}}$$